# Loop through values of one variable to populate another variable - SPSS

Tags: python, spss

I currently have the below syntax -

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss,spssdata
varlist = [element[0] for element in spssdata.spssdata('CARD_2_Q2_1_a').fetchall()]
varstring = " ".join(str(int(i)) for i in varlist)
spss.submit("if (Q4_2 = 2 AND CARD_2_Q2_1_a = %(varstring)s) Q4_2_FULL = %(varstring)s." %locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

I thought this would just loop through the values in my variable CARD_2_Q2_1_a and populate Q4_2_FULL where appropriate. It worked in long hand without Python use, but the code above doesn't change the input file at all. Any reason why this might not be working or an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: *It worked in long hand without Python use* <-- Consider showing us your longhand syntax?  Then, add a `print` statement to your script here and verify that both syntax strings are equivalent. I suspect they will not be.

Answer (score 1):

varstring will be a string of integers joined by blanks.  Therefore, your test condition in the IF will never be satisfied.  Hence Q4_2_FULL will never be populated.  You can print out the command you are submitting to see this.

I'm not sure exactly what your desired result is, but remember that the IF command you are submitting will execute over the entire dataset.